# case statement in select for php/mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin

Good afternoon 
I have a table that has 
customer id, name,         computer,    laptop, blah, blah, blah
1,           John Doe,     Acer,        1,      blah, blah, blah

Now i have to use a select case statement among all the other select statements and joins, but i am getting this error"
Undefined index: IsLaptop in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\Index.php on line 81

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

echo '<h1>Customers:</h1>';


require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$q = "SELECT CONCAT(left(FirstName,1),left(MiddleName,1),LastName) AS UserName,
      CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' ', MiddleName) AS Name,
      (NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
      (OldCustomerID) AS oldcustomerid,
      (birthmonth.Description) as birthmonth,
      (cars.Description) AS cartype,
      (carcolor.Description) AS carcolor,     
      (computers.Description) AS computer,
      (race.Description) AS race,
      (residence.Description) AS residence,
      (IsLaptop) AS IsLaptop




  FROM customer
    INNER JOIN cars ON(customer.CarID = cars.CarID)
    INNER JOIN birthmonth ON(customer.BirthMonthID = birthmonth.BirthMonthID)
    INNER JOIN carcolor ON (customer.CarColorID = carcolor.CarColorID)
    INNER JOIN computers ON (customer.ComputerID = computers.ComputerID)
    INNER JOIN race ON(customer.RaceID = race.RaceID)
    INNER JOIN residence ON(customer.ResidenceID = residence.ResidenceID)

WHERE (NewCustomerID) >= 500 and (NewCustomerID) <= 600
order by LastName, FirstName

       "; 
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q ); if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc));}
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if ($num >0) {
    echo "<p> There are currently $num of customers.</p><br/>";


    echo '<table  border="1">
              <tr>
                <td>Customer ID</td>
                <td>Old Customer ID</td>
                <td>Customer Name</td>
                <td>UserName</td>
                <td>Car</td>
                <td>Car Color</td>
                <td>Birth Month</td>
                <td>Computer Brand</td>
                <td>Laptop</td>
                <td>Race</td>
                <td>Residence</td>



              </tr>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo   '<tr>
                <td>' . $row['customerid']. '</td>
                <td>' . $row['oldcustomerid']. '</td>
                <td>' . $row['Name'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['UserName'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['cartype'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['carcolor'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['birthmonth'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['computer'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['IsLaptop'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['race'].'</td>
                <td>' . $row['residence'].'</td>


                </tr>'; }

        echo '</table>';
            mysqli_free_result ($r);
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">There are currently no records to show</p>';
}
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

islaptop should be a variable i presume?, in php thats

```
$islaptop
```

Comment: not sure how to put it, tried CASE(IsLaptop), but that didn't work either. the (IsLaptop) pulls from the database, the islaptop = case was because i was still getting the line error from just case (IsLaptop).

Comment: Nope that wasn't the answer then i get an error -- Notice: Undefined variable: islaptop in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\Index.php on line 45
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= CASE (IsLaptop) WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' END' at line 11

Comment: $q = "SELECT CONCAT(left(FirstName,1),left(MiddleName,1),LastName) AS UserName,
   CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' ', MiddleName) AS Name,
   (NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
   (OldCustomerID) AS oldcustomerid,
   (birthmonth.Description) as birthmonth,
   (cars.Description) AS cartype,
   (carcolor.Description) AS carcolor,   
   (computers.Description) AS computer,
   (race.Description) AS race,
   (residence.Description) AS residence,
  $islaptop = CASE (IsLaptop) 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
         WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' END 
  FROM customer

Comment: INNER JOIN cars ON(customer.CarID = cars.CarID)
 INNER JOIN birthmonth ON(customer.BirthMonthID = birthmonth.BirthMonthID)
   INNER JOIN carcolor ON (customer.CarColorID = carcolor.CarColorID)
 INNER JOIN computers ON (customer.ComputerID = computers.ComputerID)
 INNER JOIN race ON(customer.RaceID = race.RaceID)
 INNER JOIN residence ON(customer.ResidenceID = residence.ResidenceID)
 
WHERE (NewCustomerID) >= 500 and (NewCustomerID) <= 600
order by LastName, FirstName
     
    "; 
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q ); if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc));}
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

Comment: echo   '<tr>
    <td>' . $row['customerid']. '</td>
    <td>' . $row['oldcustomerid']. '</td>
    <td>' . $row['Name'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['UserName'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['cartype'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['carcolor'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['birthmonth'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['computer'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['$IsLaptop'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['race'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['residence'].'</td>
  
    
    </tr>'; }

Comment: Basically what i need, is if IsLaptop = 1, then i need it to say Yes in the column under Laptop.  (didn't put that code in reference. I can get it to work in myPHPadmin, but not come up when loading the page into firefox

Comment: I know if i need to use the case in regular php, i need a switch, but i don't know if i need it for a sql query